# Either this secret is disabled or you do not have the "Get" secret permission

Tags: azure-keyvault

On browsing disabled secret version, getting error "Either this secret is disabled or you do not have the "Get" secret permission". I have full permissions on secret (checked thru Access Policies). Any help on how to enable older version again?

Answer (score 37):

You should be able to enable it by right-clicking on the disabled version in the list and choosing "Enable"

Comment: Thank you! Why the switch enable/disable does not work? How a user suppose to know to right click there? rhetorical questions

Comment: Not theoretical questions. These are REAL questions.

Comment: And we should also be able to see the value in the portal, and only deny API/SDK access.  Not an absolute mask!

Comment: This worked only if I Enable the Current version. If I try Enabling an older version instead of the Current, the secret still remains disabled. It seems you cannot return to an older version by making it enabled. Instead, you have to add a new version with the same value that an older version had. That's a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: Wish Azure made this clear even a little bit...at least you did!

Comment: @JustAMartin - I was able to enable an older version today, so looks like it might've been an issue that's since been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the Secret Version using Cloud Shell

```
Set-AzKeyVaultSecretAttribute -VaultName 'MyKeyVault' -Name 'MySecretName' -Enable $True -Version 'NumberOfVersion'
```

This worked for me